# How can i output a string next to the result of an object

Tags: javascript, html, string, object, properties

i have an object

```
var a = {
 type: '{type}'
}
```

i have written code to get the 'type' property of an object and display it. the output is correct but now i want to add a string before printing the output.

right now the output is:   sarah

I want the output to have a "name:" before it so the output becomes: "name: sarah"

how can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `'name: ' + codeToGetTypeProperty(a)` ? Are you asking how to do string concatenation? Or how to declare strings in the first place?

Comment: string concatenation. i tried this: type: var a = {
 'Type: + {type}'
} it doesn't work still

Comment: What do you expect the result of `{ 'Type: + {type}' }` to be? The `{...}` denote an *object literal*. Object literals always have the form `{key: value, key: value, ... }`. Why did you prefix `var` with `type: `? Also, `'Type: + {type}'` would be a single string that literally contains the character sequence `Type: + {type}`. Maybe reading [a tutorial about strings](http://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html#h_OBbEvqxHHH) would be helpful? (the rest of the tutorial is also worthwhile to look at if you have troubles with the basics).

Comment: {type} is an object literal. how can i add the "name:" before displaying the object literal

Comment: In all your examples, `{type}` is the content of a string literal. Please read how to provide a [mcve], then we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
var a = {
 type: 'Sarah'
}

document.write("Name: "+a.type);
```